# If at least one element of list1 is in list2?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

Having the following:

```
public List<int> List1 { get; set; }
...
var x = GiveMeObject(); // x.List2 --> each element on list2 has an Id (int).
...
bool containsAtLeastOne = ???
```

What is the easiest/fastest/shortest way (in linq) to verify if at least 1 element of list1 is in the list2 ?

Thanks

Comment: This is where the Enumerable.Any method comes into play. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

alternative: [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx)

```
bool containsAtLeastOne = List1.Intersect(x.List2.Select(e => e.Id)).Any()
```

If your collections are getting large, you should use `Intersect` instead of `Contains`, since `Intersect` is at least as fast as `Contains`. Depending on your collecions, `Contains` can get slow quickly.

If your collections are quite small (< 1000 elements), this difference would probably not matter.

---

If you don't mind a non-LINQ way and some more lines of code, you could use

```
var tmp = new HashSet<int>(x.List2.Select(e => e.ID));
tmp.IntersectWith(list1);
bool containsAtLeastOne = tmp.Any();
```

which will probably be faster than the LINQ approach.

Comment: In my case I am comparing huge lists and performance is critical. This is why I chose your answer as the correct one.

Comment: But it needs more memory than `Contains`. @Dryadwoods: Note that even `Enumerable.Any` and `Contains` break as soon as the value was found(which might be at the beginning or at the end though). So the more likely it is that the value exists, the smaller the difference to `Intersect` is even with large collections.

Comment: @TimSchmelter In the *best* case, `Contains` is as fast as `Intersect`, but never *faster*. In the *worst* case, the speed difference is *huge* (as in *exorbitant huge*). You're probably right in saying that `Intersect` needs more memory, since it first copies one collection to a `Set`.

Comment: This was a considerable boost to performance.

Answer (score 8):

```
bool containsAtLeastOne  = x.List2.Any(li => List1.Contains(li.Id));
```